# Postgresql collation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

is it posible to define collation for connection? I'm connecting to postgresql server 9.3 via php pdo. I know that I can set collation for server, column or define it in select statement but I need it for connection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set a collation in your connection. However, if you only need to change the collation for data representation and not for ordering, you can always add the following parameters to your connection string:

> lc_monetary (string)
>   Sets the locale to use for formatting monetary amounts, for example with the to_char family of functions. Acceptable values are system-dependent; see Section 22.1 for more information. If this variable is set to the empty string (which is the default) then the value is inherited from the execution environment of the server in a system-dependent way.
>
> lc_numeric (string)
>   Sets the locale to use for formatting numbers, for example with the to_char family of functions. Acceptable values are system-dependent; see Section 22.1 for more information. If this variable is set to the empty string (which is the default) then the value is inherited from the execution environment of the server in a system-dependent way.
>
> lc_time (string)
>   Sets the locale to use for formatting dates and times, for example with the to_char family of functions. Acceptable values are system-dependent; see Section 22.1 for more information. If this variable is set to the empty string (which is the default) then the value is inherited from the execution environment of the server in a system-dependent way.

Source: [Client connection locale and formatting (Postgres 9.3 documentation)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT)

Comment: I need to order data.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve? Otherwise it is hard to find a way around it.

Comment: I have some data in column "name" for example. I need select data from this column and sort them.


`SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY name"` default collation
`SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY name COLLATE "de_DE"` specific collation for german clients

I would like to sort data without specifying collation in order clause and set collation for connection

Comment: So what you are saying is that your database is being accessed by customers speaking different languages but all customers that speak, say, German will use the same connection, right?

Comment: Yes, same connection and different languages (collation).

Comment: Sorry I thought I had written a comment! Well, the bottom like is that AFAIK you cannot assign a collation to a connection, so you are going to have to do it in a per-query basis. Having said that, you could create a table to store all the roles you use to connect to your database along with their collation, and then create a stored procedure that uses `current_user` to return the collation to use in your query. If you like this solution I would be more than happy to show you the code as part of the answer.

Comment: Have you looked into this? How did you end up solving the issue?

Comment: I'll use COLLATE in ORDER BY clause.